# Testing with Detox and JSI is failing due to META-INF

Tags: android, react-native, detox

We are using react native jsi contacts and trying to setup detox in our app. The build is failing constantly with the error

```
Execution failed for task ':react-native-jsi-contacts:mergeDebugAndroidTestJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
   > 21 files found with path 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' from inputs:
```

This is happening even after adding these lines to jsi contacts

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    excludes = ["**/libc++_shared.so", "**/libfbjni.so"]
  }
```

and to our app's build.gradle

```
exclude 'META-INF/**'
exclude 'META-INF/**'
```

What are we missing? Regular build without detox is working fine. It's only the test build that's failing.

Comment: I have the same exact issue. Where you ever able to find a solution?

Comment: The same issue happened to me, If you managed to solve please post your answer here

Comment: Had the same problem with a different library. Issue was that I was missing the `app:` prefix in the detox build command.
`"build": "cd android && ./gradlew app:assembleRelease app:assembleAndroidTest ...`